# Flutter Riverpod listview index length

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I have a listview which is using flutter_riverpod. The listview have 2 variable.
First variable is word text and second variable is length of index.

```
ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: ref.watch(itemsProvider).length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(ref.watch(itemsProvider)[index]),
                            Text(ref.watch(itemsProvider)[index].length),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

I am using this listview.builder. the first text of Row is working but second text of Row is not working.
The error:

> the argument type 'int ' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'string'

How can I solve this problem. The is no problem in widget. I am using consumerwidget, ref and widgetref. and scopped runapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text` widget seeks from `String`, Use string format

```dart
 Text("${ref.watch(itemsProvider)[index].length}"),
```

Also, you can use `.toString()`

More about [dart-core](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/dart-core-library.html)